# Output from preprocess_views_view_field in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, theming

I tried to alter the Output of an View-field with function in Drupal 8:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  $view = $variables['view'];

  if ($view->storage->id() == 'myview' && $variables['field']->realField == 'field_sterne_value') {

    $string = "";
    $sterne = intval($variables['field']->getValue($variables['row']));

    for ($i=1;$i < $sterne;$i++){
      $string .= "<img src='/themes/mytheme/img/stern.png'>";
    }

    $variables['mystar'] = $string;
  }
}
```

The output should show the stars as Images, but shows the html-Code in Frontend.
I tried different encoding with htmlentities and html_entity_decode.
But it does not work or I did encoding in a false way.

In my custom twig-template I use {{mystar}}.
But the same problem exists when I use the original template with {{output}}.

Where is my error?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the original template with `{{ output }}`, if you put the string in a markup object:

```
$variables['output'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($string);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much.
The second solution with 
$variables['output'] = \Drupal\Core\Render\Markup::create($string);
works fine.
The first solution not.
I think {{ mystars|raw }} is debricated but I am not shure.